# JQuery animate text color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I animate text color with jQuery/jQuery UI. The text is currently #000. when an event is triggered I want the text color to go #F00 then fade back to #000 over 3 seconds.

I tried `effect("highlight", {}, 3000)` with highlight but it doesn't re-trigger the effect until is completed and will then continue doing it for the amount of time it was triggered... not really useful for this.

Any ideas?

C

UPDATE:

this is what I have now:

```
$("input:text[name=size_w]").keyup(function () {
            var value = ($("input:text[name=size_w]").val() == "") ? "null" : $("input:text[name=size_w]").val();
            $("#width_emb").text(value).css({ color: "red" }).animate({ color: "black" }, 3000);
        }).keyup();
```

But it's still not working the way I need. I can't re-trigger the initial color change until the animation is finished. if the event is re-triggered before the 3 seconds is u I need to abandon the animation as start it again.

Comment: Post the code that you are using so far instead of expecting some1 to write it for you.

Comment: @Andrej already did `effect("highlight", {}, 3000)` just asking for some direction. Feel free NOT to comment if you're not here to help.

Comment: You edited your answer 2 mins after I posted comment.... It was not clear what you tried when I was commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need JqueryUI it adds support for colour animation

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

From the JQueryUI site:

> The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to animate colors as well. It's >heavily used by the class transition feature and it's able to color animate the following properties:
>
> - backgroundColor
> - borderBottomColor
> - borderLeftColor
> - borderRightColor
> - borderTopColor
> - color
> - outlineColor

In response to the updated question if you are halfway through an animation and you want it to stop or restart if you click again you can call .stop()
http://api.jquery.com/stop/
You can also use this to clear any queued animations.

Comment: I have the same issue.. I can't re-trigger the initial color change until the animation is finished. if the event is re-triggered before the 3 seconds is u I need to abandon the animation as start is again.

Just updated my code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly the behaviour you want? What do you want to happen if you click again while the transition is in progress?

Comment: I've added a possible solution

Comment: Yes..exactly that. sorry if i wasn't celar.

Comment: this is working perfectly: `$("#width_emb").text(value).stop(true, true).css({ color: "red" }).animate({ color: "black" }, 3000);` Does that look like a good solution?

Comment: I can't check it at the moment, but that looks like it should work