# Why is this jquery event not being triggered?

Tags: jquery

Why does the jquery animation not work, yet the simpler inline style is triggered onmouseout?

http://jsfiddle.net/FZLnE/1/

```
function bigImg(x){

  jQuery(x).stop().animate({
      color: "#fff"
  }, 200);

}

function normalImg(x)
{
    x.style.color="green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single **numeric** value
>
> From [jQuery Animate Docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You simply cannot animate colors as they are non-numeric.  There is a plugin called jQuery Color that looks like it might help, it is linked to on the jQuery animate API page

Answer (score 0):

Actually Thomas Lai was right. It works with UI checked.

In any case `.hover()` takes two functions- one for mouseover, one for mouseout. You could use `.on('mouseover')` and `.on('mouseout')` too.

http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/FZLnE/8/

```
<div class="one">This is a link</div>
```

jq

```
$('.one').hover(function(){
  jQuery(this).stop().animate({
      color: "#fff",
      marginLeft:50
  }, 200);  
}, function(){
    this.style.color="green";
})
```

Comment: The thing is, I was animating my links like that before, but they were behaving a little weirdly. I was hoping by defining them in the element <div class="one" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)">This is a link</div> I could fix this. 

Could this be animated by defining in the element?

Comment: Thomas Lai posted that it works with UI checked, which it did. Yes you can continue to do that but it's cleaner to use the coding style above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `color` using simply jQuery. You need to use jquery UI to do so.

Please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7918949/1577396)

and also check out this development of [new plugin](https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com) by jQuery team to support color animations and many other good stuffs.